# How can I remove all decimals from a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove all decimals from a number? I want to get the number as specified below. I need to remove decimal points only. I am not getting the logic for it.

If number x= 1.1.6;
then I want result as 116

and when x=0.0.6;
then I want result as 6.

Comment: how can number be `1.1.6` ? its not possible for a integer to have that value. i would suggest you consider this as a string and parse it

Comment: @dreamweiver - OP didn't say it was an integer. Obviously this is a [Dewey Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification) number. :-) (The point is, it would clearly have to be a string value, not an integer.)

Comment: what is the end goal? Are these version numbers? `10.11.2` will become the same as `10.1.12` but they're both different. Perhaps `let [major, minor, patch] = "10.11.2".split('.').map(x => parseInt(x, 10));`

Answer (score 0):

Since `1.1.6` is not a valid numerical value in JavaScript, I assume that you're starting with a string. You can get the result as an integer value with:

```
parseInt(number.replace(/\./g, ''))
```

If desired, you can then turn that back into a string with no leading zeroes with:

```
'' + parseInt(number.replace(/\./g, ''))
```

Answer (score -1):

try this. replace all the `.` using replace method and convert to integer

```js
document.write(parseInt("1.1.6".replace(/\./g, '')))
document.write('<br>')
document.write(parseInt("0.0.6".replace(/\./g, '')))
```